# Memory allocation of struct with void* in C++

Tags: c++, void-pointers

I want to make a memory allocation of a struct like the following in C++. Is it fine to do it like:

```
m_temppkt = new pktstruct();
```

and the struct is:

```
 struct pktstruct {
   void *address;
   int length;
   struct pktstruct *next;
 };
```

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly fine. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Assuming `m_temppkt` is of type `pktstruct*`, yes.

Comment: Have you tried it..? Did it work..?

Comment: Did you check if it compiles? If it does, it's fine, unless you have other definition of fine like "compiles but is it a good practice?", you need to be more clear about it. @DavidHeffernan Maybe SO became a faster handy compiler than IdeONE, or coliru.

Comment: I don't see how any of this is related to void pointers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine to do that, but the memory in m_temmkt->address will not be allocated (i.e. you allocate space for the pointer, not for the memory the pointer will point to).

The best solution is to initialize the values using a constructor:

```
struct pktstruct {
    void *address;
    int length;
    struct pktstruct *next;
    pktstruct(void* s, int l);
};

pktstruct::pktstruct(void* a, int l)
: address(a), length(l), next(NULL)
{
}

m_temppkt = new pktstruct(NULL, 0); // initializes with { NULL, 0, NULL }
```